# Shopify CLI not recognising correct ruby install

Tags: ruby, macos, shopify, homebrew

When logging into a store with Shopify CLI I am given the following error:

"Your environment Ruby version, 2.6.3, is outside of the range supported by the CLI, 2.6.6..<3.2.0, and might cause incompatibility issues."

I am getting a general 'unexpected' error on a range of commands and believe it's due to the issue above. Thing is, I have latest ruby installed via homebrew, so it seems Shopify CLI is seeing another install.

I have tried reinstalling shopify-cli through homebrew using

```
brew reinstall shopify-cli
```

But this doesn't help.

If I run

```
ruby -v
```

I get the version mentioned in the error which shopify cli is seeing: "ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]"

Comment: Ruby has a nice project labelled rbenv that can easily give you any version of ruby you need on your system. Like all scripting languages, they come in versions, and your system, is no exception. It is well behind the curve, delivering you 2.6 when the standard today is 3.1. Try that. You do have choices there too. Other options exist depending on your skills and OS.

Comment: The latest version of ruby supported by homebrew appears to be **3.1.1**, not 2.6.3: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby

Comment: As mentioned above, it's common practice to use some ruby version manager (e.g. `rbenv`) to support switching between version as necessary between projects; but if this is your only required use case then I expect you can just upgrade the system ruby to a more modern version.

Comment: For context, [ruby 2.6.3 was released almost 3 years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/04/17/ruby-2-6-3-released/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed this, but I figured it out using [this tool](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Run `brew config` command, and look for the `CLT:` key: If it says >14.x, then you got an update from macOS v12.6 version. Please correct me if you think I might be wrong.

Just like a plus, update your [Node package](https://nodejs.org/en/) at least to v18.x. I hope that helps.